# DS-160 - Monthly Salary local currency

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas

I have to apply for a B1/B2 visa on a US Embassy in another country, since it's not possible to secure an appointment on my own country due to lack of availability (300+ days waiting time).

By the way, I also couldn't expedite the appointment, so I have to try from a neighbouring country.

When it comes to monthly salary, it asks me to put the salary in local currency. Do you know whether "local currency" here refers to the local currency of the country the embassy is in, or my own country?

Comment: Why do you assume you will not have delays with the "other country"? The same people will handle your applications (do not expect consular personals on the "other country" known how to handle people of your country. So you may expect more delays (more people should check your applications, and it is always suspicious such visa hopping).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi you're right, sorry. I updated the question. There's no appointment availability until next year, and I would need the visa within 3 months.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi this is why the US state department keeps a list of current processing times, for all visa types....https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/wait-times.html Also, it is perfectly normal for US consulates to process non-residents, in fact, some countries require it.

Comment: @AussieJoe: No, the processing times is there for other reasons (and you get a lof of such data in many US gov sites, also where you cannot decide). Note: consulates have a geographical areas, so it is common to manage more countries. But really: some part will be handled by the consulate of your residency (only them can asses some documents). And most works is done in US (so independent of where you apply). (Consular officers will works a lot of time also in US between deployments). Visa hoping without reason is seen suspicious. Ask them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The monthly salary/income question for the B category visas is asking for your monthly income in your local currency. So whatever currency you receive with your paycheck is what they want to know. Obviously you wont be paid in their currency, since you are visiting to only get a visa. They could potentially ask you for a paycheck stub receipt to see if it matches. Good luck!

Also, it's perfectly normal to get B2 visas as a non-resident in a 3rd country. You simply have to contact the consulate/embassy and make sure they allow it. Half of them do, half of them do not. It is usually due to staffing and language support.

Changing the country for a US visa interview happens quite a bit, throughout the world for various reasons. For instance, my Russian in-laws waited a year in the Moscow queue only to have their B visa interviews cancelled, and the state department **kept the money**!! We had to repay and wait another year to have their B2 appointments in Budapest, in which they were granted US tourist visas. They have already been here with us in the US for 6 months and are going home this weekend. I hope it works out for you.

Comment: Sounds good. Thank you!